# SHA256 wrong identification

Tags: decode, hashcode

I'm trying to identify this hash code below for hours:

`$6$VQoztKJH$0aL8rygMd8gfX7m8cTRWOn4pqQ6bA/jkPyQSnzU0g10E0UiMQjIijs/66vflY7cMrGSKmmiBWE7r8oNCDQc3D/`

No, it's not sh-2 nor `sha256`.

Can it be an unidentified one?

Answer (score 2):

The `$6` indicates that the hash is from the `SHA-512` algorithm, see [`man 3 crypt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html):

> ```
>    If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$"
>    followed by a string optionally terminated by "$", then the
>    result has the form:
>
>           $id$salt$encrypted
>
>    id identifies the encryption method used instead of DES and this
>    then determines how the rest of the password string is
>    interpreted.  The following values of id are supported:
>
>           ID  | Method
>           ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>           1   | MD5
>           2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
>               | Linux distributions)
>           5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
>           6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
> ```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct I think this is sha512crypt $6$, SHA512 (Unix) 2 , but im unable to crack it using hashcat  damn :X